# Using Forever Store all my error and warn logs separately in their respective folders?

Tags: node.js, forever

I am using `Forever` to run my NodeJs App, By default, Forever is saving my log files under `/.forever` folder with `XXXX.log` filename, but I want to store all my error and warn logs separately in their respective folders.

Can anyone please tell me how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

forever start -o out.log -e err.log my-script.js

```
-l  LOGFILE      Logs the forever output to LOGFILE
-o  OUTFILE      Logs stdout from child script to OUTFILE
-e  ERRFILE      Logs stderr from child script to ERRFILE
-p  PATH         Base path for all forever related files (pid files, etc.)
```

For details check [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever)

Comment: I ran above command but now my server is not running because when I am using the command `forever stop my-script.js` nothing is stopping. Also, my serve is not taking any requests.

Comment: what does forever list say ?

Comment: forever list is showing the process but forever stop is not working and also server not responding to requests.

Comment: Also if my app.js is running then I have added an `error` log but where is `err.log` created, because it must have that log entry ?